Why is "Data Breakpoint" missing from Visual Studio 2022 when debugging?
Within the "Breakpoints" window, the "New" combobox dropdown would have two options:
"Data Breakpoint..."
"Function Breakpoint..."
But "Data Breakpoint" is missing. What happened here?

Is this missing for anyone else? I can't recall when this has gone missing for me, or if any updates have affected it.

What is the version you are using? Will the Data Breakpoint option show up if you update to the latest version 17.11.4?

This isn't how I used to set Data Breakpoints, but it's a working alternative for me right now.
From MSDN link

You can also select New > Data Breakpoint in the Breakpoints window or
right-click an item in the Autos, Watch, or Locals window and select Break when value changes in the context menu.

